# Stored procedure not returning correct output

Tags: sql-server-2008

Declaration of stored procedure :

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE countingObject
        @OBJ1_count INT OUTPUT,
        @OBJ2_count INT OUTPUT,
        @OBJ3_count INT OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT @OBJ1_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OBJECTS 
                              WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'OBJ1');
        SELECT @OBJ2_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OBJECTS 
                              WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'OBJ2');
        SELECT @OBJ3_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OBJECTS 
                              WHERE OBJECT_NAME='OBJ3')
   END;
```

And execution is done as below

```
 DECLARE @OBJ1_coun INT 
 DECLARE @OBJ2_coun INT 
 DECLARE @OBJ3_coun INT 

 EXECUTE countingObject @OBJ1_coun OUTPUT, @OBJ1_coun OUTPUT, @OBJ1_coun OUTPUT;

SELECT  
    @OBJ1_coun as OBJ1_Count, 
    @OBJ2_coun as OBJ2_Count, 
    @OBJ3_coun as OBJ3_Count
```

Output is being returned like this

[image: Output]

The corresponding table is

[image: Table]

Kindly help me where I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you **call** your stored procedure is wrong - you're returning all three counts into `@OBJ1_coun`  ....

```
EXECUTE countingObject @OBJ1_coun OUTPUT, @OBJ1_coun OUTPUT, @OBJ1_coun OUTPUT;
                       -- OK ----         ********** WRONG    ***** WRONG
```

Try this:

```
 DECLARE @OBJ1_coun INT 
 DECLARE @OBJ2_coun INT 
 DECLARE @OBJ3_coun INT 

 EXECUTE countingObject @OBJ1_coun OUTPUT, @OBJ2_coun OUTPUT, @OBJ3_coun OUTPUT;

 SELECT  
     @OBJ1_coun as OBJ1_Count, 
     @OBJ2_coun as OBJ2_Count, 
     @OBJ3_coun as OBJ3_Count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. feeling sorry for my silly mistake but couldn't vote you as my reputation point is very less for voting...

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning all output values to the same declared variable @OBJ1_coun

try this one

```
EXECUTE countingObject @OBJ1_coun OUTPUT, @OBJ2_coun OUTPUT, @OBJ3_coun OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. feeling sorry for my silly mistake but couldn't vote you as my reputation point is very less for voting...